# Change style for selected items in a checkboxlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to define different styles for selected items in a checkboxlist that is rendered as a table?
For example, if an item is checked, I would like the text to change to bold/change color.

Comment: You can use Listitem1.attribute.add("style","...");

Answer (score 0):

Another useful note, as Mennan mentioned before:

```
protected void formViewProducts_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    CheckBoxList cblProducts = formViewProducts.FindControl("cblProducts") as CheckBoxList;
    var productsList = products.ToList();
    foreach (Product product in productsList)
    {
        cblProducts.Items[product.productCode - 1].Selected = true;
        cblProducts.Items[product.productCode - 1].Attributes.Add("style", "color: red; font-weight: bold");
    }
}
```